# Passing Data from Parent to Child In React

Tags: reactjs

I am testing if I can pass data from the parent App.js to a child component named Contact. I want to pass data when clicking on a button.

Here is the App.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Tabs from './Components/Tabs';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import SimpleMap from './Components/SimpleMap';
import NewPatient from './Components/NewPatient';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';


function App() {

  const [data,setData] = useState(false);

  const parentToChild = () => {
    setData("This is information from parent to child.");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Contact parentToChild={data} />
     <Tabs> 
       <div label="Home" class="home-page"> 
         <img src="https://news.usc.edu/files/2020/06/covid_vaccine_stock.jpg"></img>
       </div> 
       
       <div label="New Patient"> 
         <NewPatient />
       </div> 
       <div label="Locations"> 
         <SimpleMap />
       </div> 
       <div label="Appointments">
       </div>
     </Tabs> 
     <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the child component I want the data to be displayed from the parent data when I click on the button:

```
import React from 'react';
import './footer.css'


function Footer({parentToChild})
{


    return (
        <div className="Footer">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="col">
                        <h4 className="block ">About Us</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <h4 onClick={() => parentToChild(true)} className="block" >Contact</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <h4><a className="block" href={"https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/faq.html"}>COVID-19 FAQ</a></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col">
                        <h4 className="block"><a className="block" href={"https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/if-you-are-sick/quarantine.html"}>CDC Guidelines</a></h4>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Footer;
```

I am testing this functionality because I want to eventually display a popup form when I click on a button. I want to use the data from the parent to trigger a popup in a child component. The following code says that parentToChild is not a function. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

you can use state.

```
const [state, setState] = useState('')

App.js

    const buttonThatYouWantTobeClicked = (dataShouldGotoComponent) => {
      setState(dataShouldGotoComponent)
    }
 
    <Footer data={state}/>
```

then in footer.js you can check if value of props is not undefiend or null, so do something

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pass your `parentToChild` function to your Footer Component:**

```
<Footer parentToChild={parentToChild}/>
```

And if you want to show data from your child, you will need to declare it in your params:

```
const parentToChild = (input) => {
    console.log('Info from child' ,input);
    setData("This is information from parent to child.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass that information via props to the Footer component,

```js
<Footer parentToChild={parentToChild} />
```

This will trigger the callback.